# Refresh child DataContext for a tabbed window with MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabs, ninject

I am trying to build a WPF window that contains different tabs. 
To be more precise the tabs will present different aspect of a given `Person` (say a short presentation and the list of the books this person has read).
The main window has a combox that allows us to choose the person. I would like the tabs to refresh when the selected person on the combo box is changed.

```
  public interface IPerson
    {
        string Name { get; }

        int Age { get; }

        string[] BooksRead { get;} 
    }
```

For the sake of simplicity I kept only the two tabs below.

[image: This is the first tab of my window]
[image: This is the secont tab of my window]

I created my sample following MVVM principles (I use the MVVMLight framework) and I would like my tabs to have their own View controls and ViewModels.

The App.xaml has for ressource the ViewModelLocator

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel" />
  </Application.Resources>
```

Now the xaml of the mainwindow looks like

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="MainViewModel" Source="{StaticResource Locator}" />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailablePersons}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <TabControl Name="Test" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex}" Grid.Row="2">
            <TabItem Name="HomeTab"  Header="Summary">
                <views:SummaryTabControl/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Name="ContactsTab"  Header="Books">
                <views:BooksTabControl/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

Now the view of the SummaryTabControl has the following lines for DataContext

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Path="SummaryTabViewModel" Source="{StaticResource Locator}" />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

We have something similar for the other tab `BooksTabControl`...

Now here is the code of the `ViewModelLocator` based on the Ninject IoC framework.

```
 public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        private static readonly IKernel _kernel;

        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            _kernel = new StandardKernel();
            _kernel.Bind<IMainViewModel>().To<MainViewModel>().InSingletonScope();
            _kernel.Bind<ISummaryTabViewModel>().To<SummaryTabViewModel>();
            _kernel.Bind<IBooksReadTabViewModel>().To<BooksReadTabViewModel>();
            _kernel.Bind<IPerson>().ToMethod((ctx) =>
                {
                    var mainViewModelInstance = _kernel.Get<IMainViewModel>();
                    if (mainViewModelInstance.SelectedPerson == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException();
                    }
                    return mainViewModelInstance.SelectedPerson;
                });
        }

        public static IMainViewModel MainViewModel { get { return _kernel.Get<IMainViewModel>(); } }
        public static ISummaryTabViewModel SummaryTabViewModel { get { return _kernel.Get<ISummaryTabViewModel>(); } }
        public static IBooksReadTabViewModel BooksReadTabViewModel { get { return _kernel.Get<IBooksReadTabViewModel>(); } }

    }
```

Actually, the `SummaryTabViewModel` and `BooksReadTabViewModel`'s constructors depend only on the `IPerson` (see sample below). That is why I created the dynamic binding of `IPerson` to the MainViewModel `SelectedPerson` member.

```
public class SummaryTabViewModel : ISummaryTabViewModel
{
    private readonly IPerson _person;
    public SummaryTabViewModel(IPerson person)
    {
        _person = person;
    }

    public string Name { get { return _person.Name; } }
    public int Age { get { return _person.Age; } }
}
```

The trick is I would like the tabs `DataContext` to be reloaded when the `SelectedPerson` is changed. I tried different approaches, one by sending a message so that the MainWindow's codebehind forces the `DataContext` of the tabs to be reset, however, the tabs did not reload...

How, in my situation, could I force the tabs control to reload and to reask the `ViewModelLocator` for an 'updated' `DataContext` ?

The complete sample code can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/bpatra/DesignableMVVMSample)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know the locator stuff, but a simple solution is the following: remove the DataContext stuff from your usercontrol

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
   <Binding Path="SummaryTabViewModel" Source="{StaticResource Locator}" />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

EDIT: in addition to your comment. when you wanna change something because SelectedItem changed then why not do this in your MainViewModel?

```
public IPerson SelectedPerson
{
    get {...}
    set
    {
        this._selectedPerson=value;
        this.MySummary = SummaryTabViewModel(_selectedPerson);
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
    }
  }

 public ISummaryTabViewModel MySummary 
 {
    get {...}
    set
    {
        this._mySummary = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MySummary");
    }
 }
```

xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox x:Name="cbo" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailablePersons}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <TabControl Name="Test" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex}" Grid.Row="2">
        <TabItem Name="HomeTab"  Header="Summary">
            <views:SummaryTabControl DataContext="{Binding Path=MySummary}"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="ContactsTab"  Header="Books">
            <views:BooksTabControl/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for: the type of the DataContext for the SummaryTabControl is an ISummaryTabControlViewModel while SelectedItem is an IPerson...

Comment: I think you are right: its far simpler to expose the sub viewmodels as members of the MainViewModel. I would have liked to kept the construction of the view models in the ViewModelLocator but it seems complicated to notify the change... For those who are interested, I have implemented this approach here
https://github.com/bpatra/DesignableMVVMSample/commit/605c0c5302d8a872c7ce3cb579aadf728d998790